# pg_dump - how to split it into directories and files?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, version-control

I am looking for a way to dump PostgreSQL12 database model into a directory/file structure, instead of a single file - for versioning purposes.

I found this old [thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTikLHA2x6U=q-t0j0YS78txHFmdtyxJfsrsRcLqN@mail.gmail.com), which mentions this exact case and describes a `--split` flag to be used with pg_dump.

However, this option does not exist in the current pg_dump for PostgreSQL12. I also tried the option `--format=directory` but that's not it. How do I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

The directory format will write one file per table, so that sounds like a good candidate. But if you are interested in a text diff, it is of course useless.

The only thing I can think of is to dump each table, view and function separately using the `-t` option. You might still be disappointed if you want a diff of the table contents, because rows in a PostgreSQL table keep changing position.

Best practice is *not* to meddle with the database and then to reverse engineer a diff, but to use a schema versioning tool like Liquibase and write SQL diff files yourself.